# Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, lambda

Here my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  attr_accessible :position
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :topic_id
end
```

I want to fetch all `topics` with, for `current_user`, the associated `bookmark`. ATM, I do:

```
Topic.all.each do |t|
    bookmark = t.bookmarks.where(user_id: current_user.id).last
    puts bookmark.position if bookmark
    puts t.name
end
```

This is ugly and do too much DB queries. I would like something like this:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bookmark, :conditions => lambda {|u| "bookmarks.user_id = #{u.id}"}
end

Topic.includes(:bookmark, current_user).all.each do |t| # this must also includes topics without bookmark
    puts t.bookmark.position if t.bookmark
    puts t.name
end
```

Is this possible? Have I any alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hmm I'm not sure I understood your question but this may help you:

```
# code
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user, lambda { |user| includes(:bookmarks).where(bookmarks: { user_id: user.try(:id) || user} ) }

# call
Topic.for_user(current_user) # => Array of Topics
```

As you can see **the parameter** of the scope `for_user` **can be a User object OR a user id**.

Hope this helps!

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Comment: `includes` excludes unbookmarked `topics`. From your idea, I change it into a `joins` : `scope :for_user, lambda { |user| select('topics.*, bookmarks.position as position).joins("LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.topic_id = topics.id AND bookmarks.user_id = #{user.try(:id) || user}") }`.

Then in the code : `Topic.for_user(current_user)`. `joins` seems not to select attributes by default. I'm looking for a cleaner solution, but it does the work. Thank you :)