# Rails active record querying association with 'exists'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an app that allows Members to take a survey (Member has a one to many relationship with Response). Response holds the member_id, question_id, and their answer.

The survey is submitted all or nothing, so if there are any records in the Response table for that Member they have completed the survey.

My question is, how do I re-write the query below so that it actually  works? In SQL this would be a prime candidate for the EXISTS keyword.

```
 def surveys_completed
    members.where(responses: !nil ).count
 end
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use `includes` and then test if the related response(s) exists like this:

```
def surveys_completed
  members.includes(:responses).where('responses.id IS NOT NULL')
end
```

Here is an alternative, with `joins`:

```
def surveys_completed
  members.joins(:responses)
end
```

**The solution using Rails 4**:

```
def surveys_completed
  members.includes(:responses).where.not(responses: { id: nil })
end
```

---

**Alternative solution using [`activerecord_where_assoc`](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc)**:
This gem does exactly what is asked here: use `EXISTS` to to do a condition.
It works with Rails 4.1 to the most recent.

```
members.where_assoc_exists(:responses)
```

It can also do much more!

---

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association/19231664#19231664)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Comment: The first option gave this deprecation notice http://pastebin.com/KbsNiqLy. The second returned the same records 68 times because their are 68 questions so I modified it like this: members.joins(:responses).uniq.count

Comment: The deprecation notice can't be avoided because we need to type a string in order to says "IS NOT NULL" (not possible to translate this in pure ActiveRecord unless you use Rails 4). I will put a third possibily in a sec @lee

Comment: I looked more into the deprecation notice, and did this: members.includes(:responses).where('responses.id IS NOT NULL').references(:responses).count and this also works. So now it is a question of which way is the "best" way

Comment: Oh, and I am using Rails 4

Comment: @lee Oh cool then you can translate this to ActiveRecord and not have to write any line of SQL!

Comment: The Rails console still says that there is a syntax error http://pastebin.com/0phjpZ0h

Comment: I ended up going with this:     members.includes(:responses).where('responses.id IS NOT NULL').references(:responses).count

Comment: @MrYoshiji actually it's possible to do this in Rails 3 without using literal SQL strings as well:

members.includes(:responses).where(Response.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil)).count

Comment: For the second answer don't forget to use `members.joins(:responses).uniq` if you don't want duplicates

Answer (score 7):

You can use SQL `EXISTS` keyword in elegant Rails-ish manner using [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem:

```
members.where_exists(:responses).count
```

Of course you can use raw SQL as well:

```
members.where("EXISTS" \
  "(SELECT 1 FROM responses WHERE responses.member_id = members.id)").
  count
```

Comment: The other answer will not generate SQL which uses the EXIST keyword.  This way will be much more performant!

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Rails 5 and above you should use `left_joins`. Otherwise a manual "LEFT OUTER JOINS" will also work. This is more performant than using `includes` mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234998/3788753. `includes` will attempt to load the related objects into memory, whereas `left_joins` will build a "LEFT OUTER JOINS" query.

```
def surveys_completed
  members.left_joins(:responses).where.not(responses: { id: nil })
end
```

Even if there are no related records (like the query above where you are finding by nil) `includes` still uses more memory. In my testing I found includes uses ~33x more memory on Rails 5.2.1. On Rails 4.2.x it was ~44x more memory compared to doing the joins manually.

See this gist for the test:
https://gist.github.com/johnathanludwig/96fc33fc135ee558e0f09fb23a8cf3f1

Answer (score 7):

### where.missing (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces a new way to check for the absence of an association -  [where.missing](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing).

Please, have a look at the following code snippet:

```rb
# Before:
Post.left_joins(:author).where(authors: { id: nil })

# After:
Post.where.missing(:author)
```

And this is an example of SQL query that is used under the hood:

```rb
Post.where.missing(:author)
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
# LEFT OUTER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "posts"."author_id"
# WHERE "authors"."id" IS NULL
```

As a result, your particular case can be rewritten as follows:

```rb
def surveys_completed
  members.where.missing(:response).count
end
```

Thanks.

**Sources:**

- [where.missing official docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing).
- [Pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727).
- [Article from the Saeloun blog](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/21/rails-6-1-adds-query-method-missing-to-find-orphan-records.html).

**Notes:**

- [where.associated](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-associated) - a counterpart for checking for the presence of an association is also available starting from Rails 7.
- See [offical docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-associated) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508289/rails-only-find-records-where-has-many-associated-records-are-present/66217280#66217280).

Comment: Great stuff! This resolves the performance concerns of `includes` raised by other answers and is a better choice for more recent versions of Rails.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a subquery:

```
members.where(id: Response.select(:member_id))
```

In comparison to something with `includes` it will not load the associated models (which is a performance benefit if you do not need them).

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 7 you can use `where.associated`:

Before:

```rb
@account.users.joins(:contact).where.not(contact_id: nil)
```

After:

```rb
@account.users.where.associated(:contact)
```