# Rails where has_many not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Campaign` model has_many `Response`.

What I'd like to do is a search that's like `Campaign.where.not(responses.nil?)`

Basically returning a list of all campaigns that have responses.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may do it by query with `join`:

```
Campaign.joins(:responses)
```

Or by two queries without `join`:

```
Campaign.where(id: Response.pluck(:campaign_id))
```

Answer (score 7):

According to these [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508289/rails-only-find-records-where-has-many-associated-records-are-present), here are a couple of ways you can achieve this:

#### Rails 7+ `where.associated`

```rb
Campaign.where.associated(:responses)
```

#### Rails 4+

```rb
Campaign.includes(:responses).where.not(responses: {id: nil})
```

or

```rb
Campaign.joins(:responses).distinct
```

#### Rails 3+

```rb
Campaign.joins(:responses).distinct
```

##### References:

- https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-associated

Answer (score 3):

You could do a SQL join to return only the `Campaign` records with `Responses`, like this: `Campaign.joins(:responses)`

It will produce SQL like: `SELECT campaigns.* FROM campaigns
  INNER JOIN responses ON responses.campaign_id = campaign.id`