# Finding all records that has at least one association from associated models (tables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

So let's say I have this:

```rb
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruits
  has_many :flowers
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tree
end

class Flower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tree
end
```

How can I make an efficient query that would get all the `Tree` instances that would have at least one `Flower` or `Fruit` instance, or both? The idea is not getting the `Tree` that don't have any `Flower` and `Fruit` at all.

Comment: Similar question, for finding all records with at least one associated record present from a SINGLE association: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43007150/12484

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use such query:

```
Tree.left_joins(:fruits, :flowers).where('fruits.id IS NOT NULL OR flowers.id IS NOT NULL').distinct
```

it will produce this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "trees".* FROM "trees" LEFT OUTER JOIN "fruits" ON "fruits"."tree_id" = "trees"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "flowers" ON "flowers"."tree_id" = "trees"."id" WHERE (fruits.id IS NOT NULL OR flowers.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way to get all `Tree`s that have at least one `Flower` or `Fruit` is like this

```
flowers = Flower.pluck(:tree_id)
fruits  = Tree.pluck(:tree_id)
```

and then the `Tree`s you want

```
Tree.where(id: [flowers, fruits].flatten)
```

This results in 3 queries to your db, which might or might not be a problem depending on your use case.

---

A more advanced method would be to do this, which results in only one query. Note the use of `select` instead of `pluck` which makes it possible for Rails to issue just one query in the end.

```
flowers = Flower.select(:tree_id)
fruits  = Fruit.select(:tree_id)

Tree.where(id: flowers).or(Tree.where(id: fruits))
```