# How to know if an Model has a relationship set in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model like this:

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :year, use: :slugged

  has_many :events
```

I want in my controller, to get all the years that have at least one event. How can I do that?

I was trying to make this:

```
 Year.includes(:events).first.events
  Year Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `years`.* FROM `years`  ORDER BY `years`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`year_id` IN (1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

But this is returning empty sets.

Answer (score 4):

Join with events. This gives you all your years except those ones that don't have an event attached.

```
Year.joins(:events).distinct
```

Comment: This may return duplicates. One of my previous answer cover this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998

Comment: Yes. Its returning duplicates :(

Comment: `Year.joins(:events).distinct`

Comment: Or `Year.where(id: Event.select(:year_id).distinct)`. SQL `SELECT years.* FROM years WHERE years.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT events.year_id FROM events)`