# Rails Controller Index Only Display Objects with Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a Rails model called `User`. There are two different types of users. Some users have `company_profiles` in a separate table.

In my controller for my page view, I'd only like to display those users who have company_profiles. I'd also like to display their user info and their company_profile info too.

I'm not sure how to handle this in my controller and view.

What should be in my index method?

```
def index
  @users = User.scoped # ?????
end
```

And how do I loop through each user with a company profile on the index page?

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p>
    <%= user.email %>
    <%= user.company_profile.poc_first_name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you mentioned you want to show users only for which company_profile exists. So in your controller method following should be in the index method

```
def index
   @users = User.left_outer_joins(:company_profile).where("company_profiles.id is  NOT NULL")
end
```

Then in your views you can get company_profile's poc first name as follows

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <p><%= user.email %>
        <%= user.company_profile.poc_first_name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why a left _outer_ join but then removing the rows which are empty on the right side? Isn't that basically an _inner_ join?

Answer (score 1):

Making an `INNER JOIN` when loading the records from the database should work:

```
def index
  @users = User.joins(:company_profile)
end
```