# Join multiple tables with active records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to know the banner name situated in a great grandchildren tab. Here's how my data base is:

```
Inscription (where I need to start from): Item1_id
Item1: Item2_id
Item2: Banner_id
Banners: name
```

How do i get all the banners name of my inscription table with active records?

Comment: `Inscription.includes(item1: { item2: :banner })` The names `item1`, `item2` and `banner` need to match the names given to each relation (ex: if you set `Inscription has_many: :items2` then you should use `.includes(:items2)`). (You can use `.joins` with the same arguments if you want)

Comment: Thanks! @MrYoshiji If I want to add a where(name == "") how should I do it?

Comment: Just add `.where(name: "")` to the end, after all the `joins`/`includes`.

Comment: It's not working :/ it says Unknown column 'inscriptions.name' in 'where clause' I wrote: Inscription.joins(firm_office_1: { firm: :banner }).where(name: "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Inscription.includes(item1: { item2: :banner })
```

The relations names `item1`, `item2` and `banner` need to match the names given to each relation.

If you want to set a `where` statement on this query, you can do:

```
scope = Inscription.includes(item1: { item2: :banner }) 
scope = scope.where(banner: { name: "MOTD: Hello World!" })
scope = scope.where(item2: { is_favorite: true })
```

---

**Similar questions:**

- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)