# Rails join through 2 other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to join tables to get an object.

I have these models:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end

class Claim < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, dependent: :destroy
  validates :number, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :claims
end
```

Basically I want to select all claims that belong to users that belong to a company.

Somethings I have tried:

(This works but is terrible and not the rails way)

```
@claims = []
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
@users = @company.users
@users.each do |u|
  u.claims.each do |c|
    @claims.push(c)
  end
end

@claims = @claims.sort_by(&:created_at)
if @claims.count > 10
  @claims.shift(@claims.count - 10)
end
@claims = @claims.reverse
```

This is close but doesn't have all the claim data because its of the user:

```
    @claims = User.joins(:claims, :company).where("companies.id = users.company_id").where("claims.user_id = users.id").where(company_id: params[:id]).order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
```

I tried this but keep getting an error:

```
    @claims = Claim.joins(:user, :company).where("companies.id = users.company_id").where("claims.user_id = users.id").where(company_id: params[:id]).order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
```

error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Claim' to association named 'company'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Any ideas what I should do or change?

Comment: Try using: `Claim.joins(user: :company)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji that works! I dont really get why? Could you explain in an answer so I can understand what is going on and give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your relations, you should use

```
Claim.joins(user: :company)
```

Because the `Company` is accessible through the relation `Claim` <> `User`.
If you wanted to join/preload/include/eager load another relation, let's say if `Claim` `belongs_to :insurance_company`, then you would add it like this:

```
Claim.joins(:insurance_company, user: :company)
```

Similar questions:

- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)

---

That being said, if you want to

> select all claims that belong to users that belong to a company

Then you can do the following:

```
Claim
  .joins(:user) # no need to join on company because company_id is already on users
  .where(company_id: params[:id])
  .order(claims: { created_at: :desc })
  .limit(10)
```

Tada!