# Rails scope filtering elements with no has_many associated elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
    scope :no_photos, -> { where('properties.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(property_id) FROM photos)') }
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property
end
```

I know that my scope is really inefficient.
I need another way to get the properties that don´t have any photos associated to them.

Any help?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319400/12484

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  scope :has_no_photo, includes(:photos).where(photos: { id: nil })
  scope :has_photo, includes(:photos).where('photos.id IS NOT NULL')
  # rails 4 or higher (thanks to @trip)
  scope :has_photo, includes(:photos).where.not(photos: { id: nil })
```

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)

Comment: Thanks, how would the opposite work?  scope :has_photo ?

Comment: I added the scope `has_photo` to my answer, hope this helps!

Comment: also `scope :has_photo, joins(:photos).where.not(photos: {id: nil})`

Comment: @Trip I added your suggestion to my answer, thanks for keeping that post up-to-date :)